# Requirements check failed for JDK (Android target: not installed)

Tags: cordova, macos-catalina, android-sdk-tools, java-home

Good day,
I am very new with Cordova and Java on my MacBook
I am trying to create my first snartphone app and I installed Cordova following [this page](https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-osx.html).
It's look like all things went well, excepted now when I try to run my app.
I only did [those step](https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted)

1. I create a project
2. I create two platform (android and ios)

I tried to to run a platform

```
cordova run android
```

But I get that error

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/pamey/Library/Android/sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/pamey/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /Users/pamey/Library/Android/sdk
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 15.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

Previoulsy, I added to ~/.bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=/Users/pamey/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/pamey/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/pamey/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$P$
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/pamey/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/pamey/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools


if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

and

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

It look like if I missed some things.

I enter the command

```
$sudo cordova requirements
```

and it printed some errors

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 15.0.2
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
Gradle: installed /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/6.8.3/bin/gradle

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 12.4
ios-deploy: installed 1.11.4
CocoaPods: installed 1.10.1
Some of requirements check failed
```

I really spend a lot of time to understand why I have

> Android target: not installed

some could help me to understand what I did wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I installed jdk-15.0.2.jdk.
The [doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#java-development-kit-jdk) says to install the version 8.
I did and it works.